# Form object not displaying properly

Tags: vb.net

I never created form objects in .net before so please bear with me. 
I have a form that is full of textboxes, comboboxes, grids, etc... In some instances we need to look at previous data as readonly and the former programmer created a separate winform which means when one form changes they both have to change. I proposed using an object of the form and make everything on it as readonly or disabled. ReadOnly for text boxes so the users can copy text.

In my class I define the object: **Private objfrmFMReadOnly As frmFM**

When the user double-clicks a record in a grid I have the following:

```
    objfrmFMReadOnly = New frmFM
    CreateReadOnlyForm()
```

**CreateReadOnlyForm** is where I make all textboxes as readonly and other certain controls disabled. I also make the main mdiparent as the parent of the object form.

I then use **objfrmFMReadOnly.Show()** to show the object form. In the load event I read the name of **Me.Name** to determine which code to run:

```
Select Case Me.Name
    Case "FM"
        PerformPreloadWork()
    Case "ReadOnlyFM"

End Select
```

As you can see nothing happens for the readonly object (yet), however, after **End Sub** the **Deactivate** event fires for the original form which I do not want. When I skip over the Deactivate event code the object appears to display the way I want. But now the original form has been shrunk to only the title bar and when I try to expand it the Deactivate event wants to run again. 
I feel I'm close yet so far away.
Can someone please help with what I need to do to create the form object?

Comment: If this data is coming from a database you probably have a DataTable somewhere. Check out the Row States and Row Versions of the DataTable which maintains values until you call an AcceptChanges.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I have not even accessed the database from the form object yet. The source form does indeed access the database. Is this what you're talking about?